# Simple show database data in JTable

Tags: java, database, swing, jdbc

I have a `JTable` that have simple structure, I want to populate it with database data.

I write this code, But now don't know to how to continue!

Comment: What is the problem you face so far? As I can see you never modify your data[][] and cols[] arrays and they are nulls so you either get some exception or your table is empty.

Comment: Do you have any specific problem or you just want to learn how to use JTable? If the latter is true, there are lots of tutorials on the Internet you can follow.

Comment: You may want to look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/jdbcswing.html

Comment: I think you have too much going on in a single class.  Decompose the problem into pieces that you can test separately.  Get the database piece working on its own before you worry about Swing or UI.

Comment: This `String[] rowdata = new String[500]` is a bad idea.  How do you know the number of rows to expect?  You could be overflowing the array.  Equally, you could be underflowing the array, leaving a multitude of empty rows.  Use a type of `List` instead.  It'd also be very reluctant to mix my database logic within the table if I could avoid it...but that's just me ;)

Comment: @PM77-1  That link is my 'learn item' of the day!  I did not realize there was a bit of Swing tucked into the JDBC tutorial!  Pity they made no mention of the EDT in it.  Accounting for the Event Dispatch Thread is important for any potentially long running task.

Comment: @NKukhar My problem is initial `data[][]` and `cols[]` with database data

Comment: @DariuszSendkowski My problem is to initial `data[][]` and `cols[]` with database data. I know how use `JTable`

Comment: @MadProgrammer i use `String[] rowdata = new String[500]` for test, Are say me to use `ArrayList<>` instead of Array?

Comment: @Sajjad Yes.  `ArrayList` is a dynamic array, capable of growing to the size you need it to become

Comment: @MadProgrammer what about vector? Is it better of `ArrayList`?

Comment: @Sajjad Not for what you want to use it for

Comment: head shaking: looks like you didn't learn a thing in your last questions ... time to grab a decent tutorial and fresh up on the basics, IMO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Simple show database data in JTable

There is no need to create a custom TableModel.

See the `Table From Database Example` code in [Table From Database](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/table-from-database/) for a simple way to load data into the DefaultTableModel and display the model in a JTable.

Comment: I need to create a custom TableMode, like this. I think that my main problem is about send data into an array or vector and then create table model.

Comment: camickr is a Swing expert.  When he tells you a DefaultTableModel is adequate, you should listen and try it.

Answer (score 3):

Anyone who is so foolish as to include an empty catch block is sure to struggle:

```
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    }
```

This is a very bad idea.  You should log or print the stack trace at minimum OR add a throws clause to the method signature and handle it elsewhere.

Your code style is poor, too.  Readability matters.  Develop a single coherent style and stick to it.

Answer (score 3):

this Exception is because of cols variable that didn't initialized anywhere.

so you should initialize all of fields in TableModels constructor or in out of TableModel.

well , then you shouldn't  using metaData or any kind of using database in TableModels main methods.

just in constructor or out side of TableModel.

like this. try:

```
class d9tableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

Connection con;
Statement statement;
ResultSetMetaData metadata;
ResultSet resultSet;
String dbName = "mydb";
String bdUser = "root";
String dbPassword = "2323";
String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb";
String query = "select * from mytable";
ArrayList<String> cols = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> data = new ArrayList<>();

public d9tableModel() {

    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, bdUser, dbPassword);
        System.out.println("Connected to database successfully!");
        statement = con.createStatement();
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);

        int c = resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
            cols.add(resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnName(i));
        }

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            ArrayList<String> row = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
                row.add(resultSet.getString(i));
            }
            data.add(row);
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("Could not connect to database");
    } finally {
        try {
            if (statement != null) {
                statement.close();
            }
            if (con != null) {
                con.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(d9tableModel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    return cols.size();
}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    ArrayList<String> row = data.get(rowIndex);
    return row.get(columnIndex);
}

@Override
public String getColumnName(int column) {
    return cols.get(column);
}}
```

this Table Model exactly maps your database table in your JTable.

sorry for my bad English every body.

good luck.

Comment: @kleopatra i run this code, And just first column was shown! after adding `i < =c` to loops, problem solved!

Comment: @Sajjad, you spotted the error correctly, the base problem was that you fixed it incompletely: adjusting only the upper bound, not the lower :-)  Omid, index in a resultset is 1-based, not 0-based, you need to edit and fix the loop appropriately.